# Parasoft Java exit code = 1 on single screen display

Tags: java, parasoft

I'm having a weird issue when running Parasoft on a single screen.

Whenever I am connected to a dock which hooks up 2 of my monitors to my laptop it works fine.

But whenever I am not connected to the dock and only have my laptop screen, when I run the software I get this error.

Is this a common issue, you guys know any solutions?[image]

Comment: Parasoft's support would probably be the place to contact.

Comment: Hi arjwolf, please contact to our support. I am sure they will help you
https://www.parasoft.com/support/

Answer (score 0):

arjwolf

you should contact Parasoft Support.
Before you contact them, please check the following as they will ask about that details :

- in your default workspace (
  C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\parasoft\soavirt_workspace) find .metadata
  directory. There should be file called .log 
  Check if you have any errors related to Java VM, or do you have ANY error there.
- in c:\Program Files\Parasoft\Test\9.10 for SOAtest & Virtualize\ you should be able to find file called eclipse.ini. Did you change something there? If yes, can you revert it?
- check if you have any Java VM options set in environment ( see JAVA_OPTIONS, chekc with command set, or echo %JAVA_OPTIONS%)